# Sending bundle from same activity to it's fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to code my first big project in Android and it's also first time I'm actually writing here. I've been trying to make this issue work for the whole day in vain, and will really appreciate if someone could show me where I'm wrong. I understand that achieving Fragment fields from the activity is bad practice, but it's the only way I don't receive null in my Fragment TextViews. Otherwise the TextViews are null. I've tried to deal with the bundle in different fragment lifecycle events (onAttach and onCreate), but nothing helped, they still don't see the values from the bundle. Thanks a lot in advance! 
And one more question, do I understand right that if I want to send a bundle from one activity to other's activity fragment, the only way is to send it to the other activity and then resend to the fragment or make an interface? Maybe there is some straight way I'm not aware about? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here is my FRAGMENT:

```
public class MatchFragment extends Fragment {
    User clickedUser=new User("","","","","",0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,false,false);

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root;
        root=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_match,container,false);
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null)
            clickedUser = bundle.getParcelable("clickedUser");
        else
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.noMatches),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        TextView nickNameTv=(TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.matchName);
        TextView firstLastNameTv=(TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.firstLastName);
        TextView paymentRequiredTv=(TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.paymentRequired);//if payment required - red "payment required", else green "can help for free"
        Button mail=(Button)root.findViewById(R.id.mailBtn);
        Button call=(Button)root.findViewById(R.id.callBtn);
        Button sms=(Button)root.findViewById(R.id.smsBtn);

        nickNameTv.setText(clickedUser.nickname);
        firstLastNameTv.setText(clickedUser.firstName+" "+clickedUser.lastName);
        boolean payment=clickedUser.paymentRequired;
        if(payment==true)
        {
            paymentRequiredTv.setText(getText(R.string.payable));
            paymentRequiredTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
        }
        else
        {
            paymentRequiredTv.setText(getText(R.string.free));
            paymentRequiredTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
        }
        mail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                mailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, clickedUser.usermail);
                mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getText(R.string.mailMessage));
               // Intent mailer = Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, null);
                startActivity(mailIntent);

            }
        });
        call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:"+clickedUser.phonenumber);
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
                startActivity(callIntent);

            }
        });
        sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"+ clickedUser.phonenumber));
                startActivity(smsIntent);
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

}
```

and the XML of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="LargeText"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:id="@+id/matchName"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/paymentRequired" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/firstLastName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePicture"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/paymentRequired" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_blue_ripple_template"
        android:text="@string/call"
        android:id="@+id/callBtn"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/smsBtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_blue_ripple_template"
        android:text="@string/mail"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/mailBtn"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/callBtn"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/callBtn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_blue_ripple_template"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/sms"
        android:id="@+id/smsBtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/paymentRequired"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/paymentRequired"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
        android:layout_below="@+id/matchName"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/paymentRequired"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstLastName"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/callBtn" />


</RelativeLayout>

Here is the ACTIVITY: 

public class OneMatchActivity extends ToolbarActivity {

    User clickedUser=new User("","","","","",0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,false,false);




     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_one_match);
            Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
            clickedUser=bundle.getParcelable("clickedUser");
            MatchFragment matchFragment = new MatchFragment();// or maybe ?? (MatchFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment));
        Bundle bundleToFr = new Bundle();
        bundleToFr.putParcelable("clickedUser", clickedUser);
        matchFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and the XML of the ACTIVITY:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context="hyperactive.co.il.helppool.OneMatchActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="hyperactive.co.il.helppool.MatchFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:background="@drawable/helpinghands"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Activity:

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction trans = fm.beginTransaction();
            trans.replace(R.id.container, MyFragment.newInstance(arg1, arg2), "tag");
            trans.addToBackStack(null).commit();



//Fragment:

    public MyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MyFragment newInstance(String arg1, String arg2)
    {
        MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("ARG1", arg1);
        args.putString("ARG2", arg2);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if(args!=null)
        {

            String arg1 = args.getString("ARG1");
            String arg2 = args.getString("ARG2");

        }

    }

//Xml

//You can use .add instead .replace method. And in the xml layout you need //to change:    
 <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="hyperactive.co.il.helppool.MatchFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />    ,  

//to this:

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but why do I actually need the .replace method? The fragment is loaded as part of the activity, there was nothing else before.

Comment: I have updated the code above. You can use .add instead .replace method. And in the xml layout you need to remove you fragment code and add a LinearLayout:    
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/container”
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

Comment: The "LinearLayout" instead of "fragment" in the XML solved my problem. The only way it finally worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the parameters in the form of Bundle from Activity to its Fragment, pass the parameters to the the Fragment via a static factory method that instantiates your fragment

```
 MyFragment myF = My fragment.newInstance(arg1,arg2);
 fragmentManager.replace(myF);
 ...
```

Comment: Fragment needs an empty constructor

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, sorry, as I've seen that if Android decides to recreate your Fragment later, it's going to call the no-argument constructor of your fragment.

Comment: You can have a no args constructor as well, and as for Android reinstantiating your fragment, it does so when your fragment is destroyed and recreated, mostly when the orientation is changed, store your variables in onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: One of the many benefits of using the one base activity + many fragments is that data passing is really quick and compact.

Comment: Having non default fragment constructor is strongly discouraged.  You can look at the official docs as to why "Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated…”. Here is a [post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/bCD7Zvd945d) from Nick B

Comment: Yes, my bad, I was thinking about static factory method all along yet kept saying constructor. Use the new instance method for data passing

Answer (score 0):

```
 MyFragment myF =  MyFragment.getInstance(arg1,arg2);
 fragmentManager.add(myF);


public class MatchFragment extends Fragment{

 public static MatchFragment getInstance(String a, String b){
   MyFragment myF = new MyFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("a", a);
    bundle.putString("b", b);
   myF.setArguments(bundle);
   return myF
 }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle b = getArguments();
    if (b != null) {
    b.getString("a");
    b.getString("b");
  }
 }
}
```